# Datasets with pre and post coronavirus data

Tags: data-request, covid19

I'm looking for public datasets that have a sort of "discontinuity" in them. Ideally, this discontinuity should be Coronavirus, and we should see a change in the distribution of the data after this discontiuity.

Any references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you define discontinuity please? ideally provide an example?

Comment: Sure: that the distribution of the data changes. More formally, that you can train a random forest model so that it detects whether the data belongs to pre or post coronavirus successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to define "after" since we are still in the middle of it. But the discontinuity surely exists between "before" and "during".

I would suggest something global and clean (machine readable), like the Google Mobility Data, which is available as global or regional CSV files.

https://www.google.com/covid19/mobility/

> The data shows how visits to places, such as grocery stores and parks, are changing in each geographic region.

https://www.google.com/covid19/mobility/data_documentation.html?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would be interested in a pre and post COVID-19 look at deaths (spoiler alert: you will notice a sudden increase in deaths in 2020). CDPH has published a query tool for top reportable causes-of-death data by demographic breakdowns with their [California Vital Data Query Tool](https://cal-vida.cdph.ca.gov/VSQWeb), it is free to register and you can get relatively up-to-date counts of deaths by reportable cause-of-death.